# Не работает Boost. Undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'

Tags: c++, boost, компоновщик

Работает `#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>`,

Но `#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"` - не работает.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
int main() { return 0; }
```

**Терминал**

```
> Executing task: /usr/bin/g++ -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lboost_thread -g /home/aram/codevs/nutshell/main.cpp -o /home/aram/codevs/nutshell/main <

/tmp/ccRxXESV.o: In function `boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(int, std::error_condition const&) const':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:656: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:659: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/tmp/ccRxXESV.o: In function `boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:686: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:689: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:701: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Эти аргументы я использовал для компиляции, их так же видно в вырезке терминала

`-DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lboost_thread`

Так же я пробовал следующее:

```
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#undef BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
```

С подобной ошибкой уже очень много вопросов, но ни один из них мне не помог :c

Пожалуйста, помогите :<

Comment: Когда собирали буст - точно модуль добавили? Либо бутс не так собрался либо пути кастомные)

Comment: я установил через apt-get.
больше ничего не делал.

Comment: удалите, откачайте через https://www.boost.org/users/download/ , соберите как указанно (там фигня ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/  && sudo./b2 threading=multi install) в процессе установки посмотрите что модуль встал (в конце там будет список что встало) если нет bootstrap поковыряйте. Да можно после сборки ldconfig дернуть

Comment: apt для откачки библиотек с возможностью конфигураций модулей - такое себе

Comment: Флажки `-l` должны быть справа от входных файлов.

Comment: @Andrey ```undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'```

Comment: есть подозрение на несовпадение разрядности. к  примеру, библиотеки 32битные, а собираете 64битное

Answer (score 3):

Порядок линковки библиотек имеет значение, они должны линковаться после объектов, которые используют символы из них:

```
-lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lpthread
```

Comment: это не помогает